# Session handling with IIS7

Tags: session, iis-7

I have a web application that until recently ran on a virtual server using IIS6, we currently run on a physical server using IIS7, and up till now have had no problems. However, a client has now complained that the application no longer works as intended.

The application runs specifically on Internet Explorer (NHS dependant) and was wrote some time ago, when modal windows didn't exist but instead opens new windows when it needs to, and quite frequently. It stores information required from page to page within a session and on each page load, checks the validity of said session. If the session isn't present or isn't what was expected, it either shows an error page or returns you to the login page. (The back button, forward button and F5 breaks the session and causes a page reload and the user has to login again to continue.)

I know the session is working since it allows a user to login and browse the application, but as soon as they open up a pop-up window, they are either shown the error screen or the login page within the pop-up window. They can continue using the application after the popup screen has shown an error, which proves that the session is still valid. If I point the user back to our old production server (IIS6) she can use the application fine without any issues and all of the popups work as intended.

The application is wrote in PHP and they are using IE8 (specific version of 8.0.6001.18702). I cannot reproduce the problem as my browser whilst still IE8, is newer. It's weird that it works on the old server but not the new one, and she is the only person who is having this issue (that has been reported to me anyway).

I'm assuming that there is a subtle difference between the two versions of IIS with regards to session handling and cookies etc, but I cannot find it. Any help/advice will be greatfully received.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a problem with the clients browser since they were using IE with a Chrome frame of sorts. Since removing that, they've been able to use the system as normal.